# Red Black Tree Book Implementation (SIGSEGV occured)

Tags: c, struct, tree, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write an implementation of title algorithm based on my university book. I've wrote the most important functions but I end up on program crash. GDB online debugger points at line 91
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                       0x0000000000400ac4 in RB_Insert (T=0x0, k=5) at main.c:90                                                  90              while((X != root) && (X->up->color == 'R')){`

5 is first value I'm trying to insert so I wonder why statement `X != root` doesn't stop it and sigsegv is printed

I will paste entire code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int key;
    char color;
    struct node *up;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root;


void in_order_tree_walk(struct node *X){
    if(X!=NULL){
        in_order_tree_walk(X->left);
        printf("%d %c\n", X->key, X->color);
        in_order_tree_walk(X->right);
    }
}

struct node* tree_search(struct node *X, int k){
    if(X==NULL || k==X->key)
        return X;
    if(k<X->key)
        return tree_search(X->left, k);
    else
        return tree_search(X->right, k);
}

struct node* tmp_node(int k){
    struct node *tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
    tmp->up = NULL;
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
    tmp->key = k;
    tmp->color = 'R';
    return tmp;
}

void tree_insert(struct node *T, struct node *Z){
    if (T == NULL){
        T = Z;
        return;
    }
    else{
        if (Z->key < T->key){
        tree_insert(T->left, Z);
        T->left->up = T;
    }
    else if (Z->key > T->key){
        tree_insert(T->right,Z);
        T->right->up = T;
    }
  }
}

void left_rotate(struct node *X){
    struct node *Y = X->right;
    X->right = Y->left;
    if(Y->left != NULL)
        Y->left->up = X;
    Y->up = X->up;
    if(X->up == NULL)
        root = Y;
    else if( X == X->up->left)
        X->up->left = Y;
        else X->up->right = Y;
    Y->left = X;
    X->up = Y;
}

void right_rotate(struct node *X){
    struct node *Y = X->left;
    X->left = Y->right;
    if(Y->right != NULL)
        Y->right->up = X;
    Y->up = X->up;
    if(X->up == NULL)
        root = Y;
    else if( X == X->up->left)
        X->up->left = Y;
    else X->up->right = Y;
    Y->right = X;
    X->up = Y;
}

void RB_Insert(struct node *T, int k){
    struct node *X = tmp_node(k);
    tree_insert(T, X);
    X->color = 'R';
    while(X != root && X->up->color == 'R'){
        if(X->up = X->up->up->left){
            struct node *Y = X->up->up->right;
            if(Y->color == 'R'){
                X->up->color = 'B';
                Y->color = 'B';
                X->up->up->color = 'R';
                X = X->up->up;
            }
            else{
                if (X == X->up->right){
                X = X->up;
                left_rotate(X);

                }
                X->up->color = 'B';
                X->up->up->color = 'R';
                right_rotate(X->up->up);
            }
        }
        else{
            struct node *Y = X->up->up->left;
            if(Y->color == 'R'){
                X->up->color = 'B';
                Y->color = 'B';
                X->up->up->color = 'R';
                X = X->up->up;
            }
            else{
                if (X == X->up->left){
                X = X->up;
                right_rotate(X);
                }
                X->up->color = 'B';
                X->up->up->color = 'R';
                left_rotate(X->up->up);
            }
        }
    }
    root->color = 'B';
}

int main(){

    root = NULL; 
    int T[] = {5,26,17,8,9,30,10,1,23};
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        printf("%d", T[i]);
        RB_Insert(root, T[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    in_order_tree_walk(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `if(X->up = X->up->up->left){` really what you wanted to do? `=` is assignment, `==` compares the values. Your compiler should warn you about that, even the online compiler does: http://ideone.com/NGGaL4

Comment: C passes all function arguments **by value**. Thus your `root` will always remain `NULL`. This is also apparent from the GDB message.

Comment: @mch yeah it's my fault, a typo, but the problem remains the same

Comment: @Daniel But I change value of `root` in `insert_tree` right? If `T`(first time it's `root`) is equal to `NULL` then swap it with inserted node. So after second line of `RB_Insert` `X` should have same value as `root`? I deleted `X != root` so it crashes because of `X->up->color` but I don't know why

Comment: It's the first inserted value so it should stop on first statement that is not true, first 'X' should be equal to 'root' so we should go out of this function.

Comment: Sorry for this comment spam but I can't edit older ones, I added an if statement `if(root == NULL) {root=Z; return;}` to tree_insert but now debugger stops at `0x000000000040078b in tree_insert (T=0x603010, Z=0x603040) at main.c:56                                    
56              T->right->up = T; `

Answer (score 0):

I changed tree_insert to

```
struct node *Y = NULL;
    struct node *X = root;
    while(X != NULL)
    {
        Y = X;
        if(Z->key < X->key) X=X->left;
        else X=X->right;
    }
    Z->up = Y;
    if( Y == NULL)
    root = Z;
    else if(Z->key < Y->key) Y->left = Z;
    else Y->right = Z;
```

and added if statement to in line 114 `if(Y != NULL && Y->color == 'R'){` and it works fine now